# Ubuntu installation does not show "Install alongside Windows" option

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I just got a new laptop, DELL Precision 5520. I have more than enough space as well as RAM, etc. I go to install Ubuntu (22.04) and it does not show the option alongside Windows. It did come with Windows 11. I am not sure if that makes a difference. I have tried past forums and the solutions do not work for me. I tried restart, shut down, etc., and no difference.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the prerequisites to get the guided "Install alongside Windows" option:

- You must have enough unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu.

  - The minimum for Ubuntu Desktop is 25GB but it would be wise to have more if you can afford it. The space must be unpartitioned. Do not create partitions ahead of time.
- You must boot the USB as UEFI if Windows is installed as a UEFI operating system.

  - Windows will be installed as UEFI unless this is a very old system upgraded from the Windows 7 era, or if for some reason you've manually installed Windows in compatibility/BIOS mode. If for some reason Windows is installed in that mode, you must also boot the USB in that mode.
- Disable "Fast Startup" in Windows. Fast Startup is actually a hybrid suspend and results in Windows not fully shutting down. When this happens, Windows can place a lock on hardware and volumes. This prevents you from using affected hardware on another operating system. If you are dual booting with Windows, you need to make sure this feature is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn off 'fast startup' in Windows. You need to turn off 'secure boot' and 'tpm' in the UEFI ( what some people incorrectly still call BIOS ). Then boot from the usb device you made with your Linux distro and try it first. See if all your hardware works, if not see if you can make it work. Next step is then to install that distribution onto an unallocated space on your hardrive or other usb device ( NOT the same as you booted from ).

Answer (score 1):

Have you partitioned your "C:" drive prior to booting from the USB installer?

If you don't have an unallocated partition, Ubuntu can't give you the option to install alongside Windows because the space belongs to the Windows OS.

To partition your drive in Windows 11, open the run box (Win+r), and run `diskmgmt.msc`

Right click your "C:" drive, and select shrink volume. Shrink a minimum of 25 GB to meet Ubuntu's requirement.

Attempt to boot off your USB installer again and you should see the install alongside Windows option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no 'secure boot' option in the UEFI. It helped to switch boot mode from 'both' to 'UEFI only'. And to disable 'fast startup' in Windows as mentioned in the other answers.