# GRUB does not appear dual-boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu Studio

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have an AR8 a few years old with Windows 11.  I was told that learning the new OS would help my 77 year old mind.  So, I downloaded Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and installed it via USB per on line instructions.  I made a 75 GB partition for Linux EXT4 "/" and 4GB partition for SWAP and selected side by side.   It was supposed to come up with a GRUB with the top selection being Studio and the bottom selection for Windows 11.   This never appeared.  At start up it goes only to Studio which appears to be working well, and I have begun learning.  Please, because I am a beginner, give me directions to a URL explaining in detail what to do to get this GRUB page to show how up and work. I searched this on line but the persons writing the explanations give short one word or two word steps which I do not understand yet.

No further help is needed, Thanks to the excellent replies from Nmath.  When the new partition was emptied and instructions followed from the link he provided, the Grub appeared and both Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and Windows 11.1 worked perfectly.

Comment: Assuming it was correctly installed then you should open UEFI ("BIOS") settings > Boot and assure "Ubuntu" is the first priority instead of "Windows bootloader". Now, learning a new OS is great but why Studio? It's a special distro geared towards audio/video professionals but not intended for daily usage.

Comment: If you made a swap partition, then you aren't following any official or up-to-date authoritative instructions. Following bad instructions leads to bad results. Swap partitions are not necessary, and if you created one, then you followed "advanced" configuration options. If you're a "beginner" this isn't a good idea. In order to get GRUB with dual boot options you need to boot the installation USB as UEFI and install Ubuntu as UEFI to match Windows 11. Otherwise you won't get the guided "Install alongside Windows" option.

Comment: Here are the qualifications that must be met to be offered the "Install alongside Windows" option: https://askubuntu.com/a/1425325. Make sure your system meets these qualifications and disable "Fast Startup" on Windows.  Then install Ubuntu. Here is the official guide to [Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you don't get the "Install alongside Windows" option, do not proceed. Go back and make sure you meet the prerequisites and that you are booting the USB as UEFI. If you're not sure how to boot a USB as UEFI, read the manual for your motherboard