# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10. I have Windows 10 on a 500GB nVME hard drive, which takes up about half the space. I have an ASUS motherboard and when I boot up the BIOS, I go to the Boot menu and select boot priority #1 to be the USB pendrive with the image of Ubuntu 22.04. Rather than getting a screen where it states that I am able to install Ubuntu next to Windows 10, I only get the option where I can either erase the drive completely to install Ubuntu, or manage the partitions myself.

So my question is, why am I not seeing the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but rather only erase the entire drive or manage the partitions manually. To put it short, the installer is not recognizing that there already is a Windows 10 installed.

Thank you and I look forward to your replies.

Comment: You can only install Ubuntu alongside Windows if you have a spare partition for Ubuntu. In your case, I guess the Windows partition takes up (nearly) your whole disk. You need to shrink the Windows partition first, then create a new partition, then install Ubuntu there. That is what is meant by "managing the partitions yourself".

Comment: I am not sure if it is still the recommendation to do the Windows partition shrinking using Windows tools, or that it is safe to do that from the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu installation does not show "Install alongside Windows" option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425322/ubuntu-installation-does-not-show-install-alongside-windows-option)