Problem with installation of Ubuntu 20.04
i'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11. I follow that steps:

create a Linux install USB with Balena Etcher
desable Boot Security
allocate space

When i try to install Ubuntu doesn't appere the "Installation type" section and i can't choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows boot manager".
I follow this guide: https://linuxsimply.com/linux-basics/os-installation/dual-boot/windows-11-and-ubuntu/.
How can i solve?

That has happened to me too, I just cancelled the installation, turned off the computer and started it with the usb being first boot drive, usually the bios allows you to choose first drive temporarily,

I do this, but it doesn't work @amar

pls see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425322/ubuntu-installation-does-not-show-install-alongside-windows-option

i  turn off 'fast startup' in Windows and 'secure boot', but nothing. @amar

If Windows 11 system, it is new. And then you typically need an Ubuntu distribution that is newer than the system to have latest kernel & drivers. Try 24.04.

I need Ubuntu 20.04 for ROS1 @oldfred

If system is too new for 20.04, you can get an older system just for that app. You may be able to use virtual box or other similar software as it isolates many parts of system. But I have never used virtual installs.

During step 7 in the link provided, choose the section that you shrank before installation. Format the partition as ext4 and set the mount point to "/" to proceed with the installation.

doesn't appere any partition, unfortunately
